# dealing with squared derivative term in non-linear second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So solving the following is relatively easy:
$\displaystyle 0 = \beta_{1} \ddot{x} + \beta_{2} \dot{x} + \beta_{3} x + \beta_{4}$

All the $\beta$ terms are real constants.
Any suggestions about how to solve for x(t) after the introduction of a term involving the square of a derivative in the last term? Is this solvable?

$\displaystyle 0 = \beta_{1} \ddot{x} + \beta_{2} \dot{x} + \beta_{3} x + \beta_{4} + \beta_{5} \dot{x}^{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first differential equation is a linear constant-coefficient equation.  These are easy to solve.
Your second is nonlinear.  These typically are much harder to solve, and often have no known closed-form solutions.

The one helpful feature it does have is that it is autonomous (i.e. the independent variable $t$ does not occur explicitly in the differential equation), and thus it can be "reduced" to a
first-order differential equation for $\dot{x}$ in terms of $x$:
if $\dot{x} = p$, we have
$$ \dfrac{dp}{dx} = \frac{\ddot{x}}{\dot{x}} = - \frac{\beta_2 p(x) +\beta_3 x + \beta_4 + \beta_5 p(x)^2}{\beta_1 p(x)}$$
However, this differential equation does not seem to have a closed-form solution in general.

Comment: In violation of comment protocol, I want to say "thanks" Robert. Equation not solvable which saves me from spinning my wheels.